# How create dynamic ORM (Object Relation Mapping ) in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want that database table will create dynamically after if user request  and that according to the table name and the column given by the user on front end and create database table should follow the ORM relation mapping as normal ORM operation.

Comment: can you give some examples for such usecase?

Comment: csv file import from front end which ll create table as user per the user given and column of the table will be the columns of the csv file

Comment: It could be possible. What codes have you tried so far? Give some code example/repository.